# textarea does not showing default text

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

i've a textarea which get's the default value from a database. for this my code is:

```
echo "<textarea readonly='true'>".$row1['description']."</textarea>";
```

for this code the value isn't coming. my output is like this.

[image]

i thought it may be some database problem. but when i write this:

```
echo "<textarea readonly='true' placeholder='".$row1['description']."'></textarea>";
```

the output shows the data.

[image]

when the database data is small then placeholder is ok. but if data will be large then it'll not show a scroll. anybody can help me.

this is the [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ratdon/kR4Sk/1/)

Comment: 1. Your first command is supposed to work. Maybe you have some JS deleting it on load or something? 2. If you'll upload your code to http://www.jsFiddle.net it'll be easier for us to locate your problem

Comment: [This works](http://jsfiddle.net/kR4Sk/). I'm afraid you will have to explain your problem in more details.

Comment: What kind of stuff would be in `$row1['description']`? What does the actual HTML output look like? And what CSS and Javascript is applied to the textarea? It can be caused by any number of things, so you need to show us anything that may affect the textarea.

Comment: Can you right click on your browser and click on "View Source Code"? Do you see any of your input with raw HTML?

Comment: in the source code, it is showing the data. the style and script applied to the textarea is `jquery ui button`. with the extra style of this.

`
textarea{
 height:70px;
 width:300px;
 resize: none;
}`

new to jsfiddle. so unable to link the external css and js files.

Comment: here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ratdon/kR4Sk/1/

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `button()` on the jQuery object wrapping the textarea. `textarea`s are not button-like controls. They are designed to be typed into, not just clicked.

Comment: i'm using the button() for styling only. i've used them with all my inputs and they are working like gem. with text area only i'm getting a problem.

Comment: then how can i apply the same style to textarea as i'm giving to input elements with `button()`. is there any other method to style textarea with jquery UI formatting used in the page?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you don't have the scrolling in the text box; then this might help:

PHP:

```
echo "<textarea readonly='true' placeholder='".$row1['description']."' id='"TextArea"' style='"max-height:100px;min-height:100px; resize: none"'></textarea>";
```

CSS:

```
#TextArea{
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
resize: none;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The result is that you style the text area to a size, then say you don't want it to resize and you want it to scroll on the y axis. I've put the styling of the text in both the style= and id so it's up to you how you want this.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the textarea is:

```
<textarea rows='10' cols='70' name='xx' id='xx'>
   <?php echo $row1['description']; ?>
</textares>
```